# Are wchar_t and char16_t the same thing on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, char

I have an instance of `std::u16string`, can I pass its `c_str()` to a Win32 APIs which expects `LPCWSTR`, without any kind of conversion? For example, can I safely do this:

```
auto u16s = std::u16string(u"Hello");
::SetWindowTextW(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(u16s.c_str()));
```

*Updated*, MSDN says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2017) `wchar_t` is UTF-16LE, while `char16_t` is just UTF-16 with no endian specified. Is it safe to assume then that `char16_t` is also always UTF-16LE on Windows? Or would that be MSVC compiler specific, and so it can possibly be UTF-32LE (or maybe UTF-16BE) if I complile with GCC, for example?

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on the C++ compiler used in the toolchain - which is usually some version of Visual C++ as you normally get the Windows SDK bundled with Visual Studio. But there are GCC and MINGW based compilers with Windows SDK's that can be used (Code::Blocks etc.) in which case you need to be more careful about the strict separation of windows types (WCHAR, TCHAR, INT) and compiler types (wchar_t, std::*, int32_t etc.) and whatever that particular compiler has done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to make amends to @jamesdlin's [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53293171/1746503) though his answer is correct.

Before C++11, there are `char` and `wchar_t`, and hence specialize `std::basic_string<>` to `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

However, the width in bits of `wchar_t` is platform-specific: on Windows it is 16-bit while on other platforms, its 32-bit.

And with the advent of C++11, the standard [adds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) `char16_t` to represent 16-bit wide characters; thus on Windows, `std::u16string` happens to be interchangable with `std::wstring` in most contexts, because they are both able to represent 16-bit wide characters.

> The wchar_t type is an implementation-defined wide character type. In
>   the Microsoft compiler, it represents a 16-bit wide character used to
>   store Unicode encoded as UTF-16LE, the native character type on
>   Windows operating systems.

But the newest MSDN seems to add some [aside notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/string-typedefs?view=vs-2017#wstring) for code using `std::wstring` yet intend to be portable:

> The size of wchar_t is implementation-defined. If your code depends on
>   wchar_t to be a certain size, check your platform's implementation
>   (for example, with sizeof(wchar_t)). If you need a string character
>   type with a width that is guaranteed to remain the same on all
>   platforms, use string, u16string, or u32string.

As for LE(little-endian), it should be architecture-specific, IIRC. and most architectures today use LE.

Comment: Anyone who cares about portability should be avoiding UTF-16 anyway.  It has all of the disadvantages of UTF-8 and of UTF-32 and none of their advantages.  Windows is stuck with UTF-16 because of bad timing; UTF-8 didn't exist yet when Microsoft added Unicode support.

Comment: @jam: If your portable code processes UTF-16 encoded files, you certainly shouldn't avoid UTF-16. There are also advantages to using UTF-16: It is a fixed-width encoding for a wide range of code points (the entire BMP), and it results in more compact representation for some Asian scripts. Also, if you are interfacing with Java or .NET, UTF-16 is a viable option. It's what both of the aforementioned use as their internal string representation. Choosing UTF-16 here results in fewer conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [`WCHAR` strings on Windows are UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings).

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2017) MSDN says `wchar_t` is UTF-16LE, while `char16_t` is UTF-16. Does it mean then that UTF-16LE is the same thing as UTF-16?

Comment: The "LE" in UTF-16LE means "little-endian".  All modern processors you use (and that you'd find Windows one) are almost certainly going to be little-endian, so in practice UTF-16 is the same as UTF-16LE on Windows.

Comment: So is it safe to say that `char16_t` is always `UTF-16LE` on Windows? Or is it MSVC compiler specific and and it can be (say) `UTF-16BE` in GCC?

Comment: @avo it is platform-specific, not compiler-specific. Windows is a little-endian platform. That being said, it is possible to store UTF-16BE strings in `std::wstring` and `std::u16string` with extra work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what about Windows on ARM32 / ARM64?

Comment: @VTT ARM has both big-endian and little-endian modes, but AFAIK, in practice almost everybody uses it in little-endian mode.