# Is casting strings from `wchar_t` to `char16_t` legal if encoding and width is the same?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

On Windows, `wchar_t` is a UTF-16(LE) formatted character, which is -- for the most part -- equivalent to `char16_t`. However, these two character types are still distinct types in the C++ type-system -- which makes me uncertain whether converting between *sequences* of these two character types is legal as per the C++ standard.

My question is this: In C++17, is it legal to perform the following casts, and to **read from** the converted pointers:

- `reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(char16_ptr)` where `decltype(char16_ptr)` is `const char16_t*`, and
- `reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(wchar_ptr)` where `decltype(wchar_ptr)` is `const wchar_t*`

For the purposes of this question, assume the following:

- `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(char16_t)`, and
- `wchar_t` is formatted the same as `char16_t` (as is the case on Windows)

Basically, is this a violation of a strict-aliasing?

My understanding that the *cast* itself is valid thanks to [`[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#7), but that the result of the cast cannot safely be used since the type is being aliased by something that isn't `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`. Is this interpretation correct?

---

**Note:** Other questions have been asked regarding `wchar_t` and `char16_t` being the same, but this question is *not* a duplicate of those as far as I can tell. Notably, the question "[Are wchar_t and char16_t the same on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53293159/1678770)" actually performs a `reinterpret_cast` between pointers, but none of the answers actually address whether this cast was ever legal in the first place.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to convert from a pointer to one type to a pointer to another type. The only problem you might run into would be compiling on Linux where ```wchar_t``` is the same as ```char32_t``` and you'll end up thinking you've hit a null terminator before the end of the string.

Comment: The conversion is perfectly legal, but it doesn't mean *using* (i.e. reading from, writing to) the pointed object is legal; this could be a violation of strict-aliasing -- which I think it is. The question is whether this is a violation, or is legal.

Comment: Beware! `wchar_t` on Windows is unsigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already know the answer to this: [strictly speaking, no](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8).

`wchar_t` is not `char16_t`. Neither derives from the other. Neither is similar to the other. Neither is a signed/unsigned version of the other. Neither is an aggregate containing the other.And neither of them is a bytewise type (`char`, etc).

So you cannot access a `wchar_t` through a pointer/reference to a `char16_t`.

If strict avoidance of strict aliasing is your goal, you're going to have to copy the data to a different object. That *is* valid, assuming they both have the same representation.

Comment: That's what I feared; too bad. I wasn't sure if there was any flexibility with layout-compatibility thanks to the values being trivially copyable. I guess I'll have to `std::copy`